# slicing dictionary with values

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
d = {1: 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'c', 5:'c', 6:'c'}
```

I want to slice this dictionary such that if the values in the end are same, it should return only the first value encountered. so the return is:

```
d = {1: 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

I'm using `collections.defaultdict(OrderedDict)` to maintain sorting by the keys.

Currently, I'm using a loop. Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

---

**UPDATE**

the dictionary values can also be dictionaries:

```
d = {1: {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1'}, 2:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b2'}, 3:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'c1'}, 4:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'c1'}, 5:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'c1'}, 6:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'c1'}}
```

output:

```
d = {1: {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1'}, 2:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b2'}, 3:{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'c1'}}
```

Comment: Is the dict always ordered by its keys? I see that you have 1,2,3,4,5,6 for keys. If so, then use a list instead as a dictionary is unnecessary.

Comment: Loops are pythonic. I wouldn't say comprehensions are always more pythonic than loops, this is subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a list-comprehension to achieve your result

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> d = {1: 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'c', 5:'c', 6:'c'}
>>> n = [(min([k[0] for k in list(g)]),k) for k,g in groupby(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[1])]
>>> n
>>> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

The above expression can also be written as

```
 >>> from operator import itemgetter
 >>> n = [(min(map(itemgetter(0), g)), k) for k, g in groupby(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))]
```

You can cast this to `dict` by simply using

```
>>> dict(n)
>>> {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

This obviously don't maintain order of keys, so you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(n))
>>> OrderedDict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')])
```

Comment: This comes down to a matter of preference, but you can also use `operator.itemgetter`: `[(min(map(itemgetter(0), g)), k) for k, g in groupby(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))]`. I upvoted nonetheless :).

Comment: thanks! this works but it doesnt when the values are also dictionaries. sorry, i have updated the OP

Comment: @AbhishekThakur I checked it is actually working if values are `dict`. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of for loop - you can do it this way:

```
{a:b for b,a in {y:x for x,y in sorted(d.iteritems(), reverse=True)}.iteritems()}
```

But it is not so pythonic and not so efficient.

Comment: I was also thinking the same thing. Not sure if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: I would say efficient and readable for loop is much better =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ordered dictionary with the keys representing indexes, the more pythonic way is using a list. In this case, you will use indexes instead of keys and will be able to slice the list more effectively.

```
>>> d = {1: 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'c', 5:'c', 6:'c'}
>>> a = list(d.values())
>>> a[:a.index(a[-1])+1]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, a solution with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(key=list(d.keys()),val=list(d.values())))
print(df)
   key val
0    1   a
1    2   b
2    3   c
3    4   c
4    5   c
5    6   c

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['val'])
df.index=df.key
df.val.to_dict()

{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Don't know performances issues on biggest dataset or if it is more pythonic.
Nevertheless, no loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if two last values are same:

```
d = OrderedDict({1: 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'c', 5:'c', 6:'c'})

while d.values()[-1] == d.values()[-2]:
    d.popitem()

print d
# OrderedDict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')])
```